# OOPS Chess game: Design logic once a player moves a piece

Tags: oop, design-patterns, chess

If was thinking designing chess game using OOPS principle.I am not able to think how use cases after moving a piece should be handled.
As we now when a player moves his piece from One spot to another.Few think can happen. like pawn may reach in last row new piece will be on board instead of that pawn or there can be check on opponent or this check can be check mate too.so how these cases should be handled? on which class should these logic be?does chain responsibility design pattern suit better here?

Comment: You'll probably need a mix of design patterns. I would think Command and maybe Chain of Responsibility. The overall question is too high level to answer with just one design pattern. The approach could always depend on your environment and code base. I can imagine from your question that this is a stand alone application but there is a chance this is a simple web app too.

Comment: a nice state machine might help you keep things organized.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a combination of design patterns.

For the move you can use **Command patterns** as that will help you to follow the basic moves of chase.

Then you can use **Decorator Pattern** to give the features to the different players and the boxes.

Overall you can have a **MVC pattern** where the view will be the player board itself, the controller can have the commands that are given by the user and also contain the design patterns discusses in the last couple of paragraphs.

And then you can have all the models where you define the features.